# How to change the title size in a Quarto PDF document

Tags: pdf, latex, size, title, quarto

I tried to change the size of the title of a Quarto PDF document (`scrartcl` class) without success.

This is what I tried. Per the [KOMA-script documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguide-en.pdf) section 3.6 (page 58), and as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73628198/change-title-headings-font-in-quarto-pdf-output), the commands for modifying the appearance of several elements are `\setkomafont`, `\addtokomafont`, and `\usekomafont`. However, section 3.7 (page 68) states:

> *Note that for the main title, `\huge` will be used after the font switching element title. So you cannot change the size of the main title using `\setkomafont` or `\addtokomafont`.*

Based on the `scrartcl` class code, I created a patch in the preamble to change the title size (from `\huge` to `\small` to see the effect easily):

```latex
\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\usekomafont{title}{\huge \@title \par}}{\usekomafont{title}{\small \@title \par}}
\makeatother
```

Here is the problem: the patch did not work with a Quarto PDF document when added through the `include-in-header` option. However, this approach worked perfectly on a basic `.tex` file compiled through RStudio.

Something is happening inside Quarto's processing that is preventing to get the wanted effect and I have not figured it out yet. I would appreciate any help in getting the change I need either by using this approach or a better one.

Thanks,

Hector

#### MWE's

##### Quarto file

```markdown
---
title: "The Title"
author: "Author"
pdf-engine: xelatex
format:
  pdf: 
    keep-tex: true
    documentclass: scrartcl
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \usepackage{xpatch}
        \makeatletter
        \xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\usekomafont{title}{\@title \par}}{\usekomafont{title}{\small \@title \par}}
        \makeatother
        
        \setkomafont{author}{\small}
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code into a finished document. To learn more about Quarto see <https://quarto.org>.
```

**Output:** [Quarto output pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO8WY.png)

##### LaTeX file

```latex
\documentclass[titlepage]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\makeatletter
  \xpatchcmd{\maketitle}{\usekomafont{title}{\huge \@title \par}}{\usekomafont{title}{\small \@title \par}}
\makeatother

\setkomafont{author}{\small}

\title{The Title}
\authorss{Author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

**Output:** [LaTeX output pdf screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qugMs.png)

#### Software used

- OS: macOS (Ventura 13.5.1)
- R v4.3.1
- RStudio v13.5.1 (via Homebrew)
- Quarto v1.3.450 (via Homebrew)
- TinyTeX package v0.46
- Document Class: scrartcl 2023/07/07 v3.41 KOMA-Script document class (article)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the [latex command for different font size](https://latex-tutorial.com/changing-font-size/) before the title text.

```
---
title: \small The Title
author: "Author"
pdf-engine: xelatex
format:
  pdf: 
    keep-tex: true
    documentclass: scrartcl
    include-in-header:
      text: |
        \setkomafont{author}{\small}
---

## Quarto

Quarto enables you to weave together content and executable code
```

---

[image: smaller title text in quarto pdf output]

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer! Although it works nicely, and I will use it in the meantime, I would like a less visible solution since this is a template that will be used by other people who do not have a LaTeX background (I'll wait a little before accepting your answer). Thanks again.

Comment: By "less visible solution" do you mean that you do not want to put latex command directly in the title? In that case, I guess you can configure a lua filter that will create an option in yaml, suppose `title-size: small`, and then add the `\small` automatically just before the title when rendering the document.

Comment: Thanks again, @shafee. I'll try your suggestion.